# Unable to change GPA to 1 decimal in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried changing GPA decimal to 1 decimal point:

```
df['Admission GPA'].round(decimals = 1)
#df.round({"Admission GPA":1})
```

Which prints it out how i want it to:

```
0      3.2
1      2.9
2      2.7
3      3.2
4      2.4
      ... 
126    1.6
127    2.8
128    3.0
129    2.7
130    2.4
Name: Admission GPA, Length: 131, dtype: float64
```

However when I print the column to see if it made changes in the dataframe
I notice it is still in 2 decimal points:

```
0      3.19
1      2.93
2      2.68
3      3.18
4      2.36
       ... 
126    1.59
127    2.85
128    3.03
129    2.72
130    2.45
Name: Admission GPA, Length: 131, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the result back to the column.

```py
df['Admission GPA'] = df['Admission GPA'].round(decimals = 1)
```

The `pd.Series.round()` function does not perform the operation in-place; it returns a new `pd.Series` which you must reassign to the column in your dataframe.

Comment: Glad to help! Go ahead and accept the answer so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.